# Lazy concatenation of sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, seq

Here's a beginner's question: Is there a way in Clojure to lazily concatenate an arbitrary number of sequences? I know there's [`lazy-cat`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-cat) macro, but I can't think of its correct application for an arbitrary number of sequences.

My use case is lazy loading data from an API via paginated (offseted/limited) requests. Each request executed via `request-fn` below retrieves 100 results:

```
(map request-fn (iterate (partial + 100) 0))
```

When there are no more results, `request-fn` returns an empty sequence. This is when I stop the iteration:

```
(take-while seq (map request-fn (iterate (partial + 100) 0)))
```

For example, the API might return up to 500 results and can be mocked as:

```
(defn request-fn [offset] (when (< offset 500) (list offset)))
```

If I want to concatenate the results, I can use `(apply concat results)` but that eagerly evaluates the results sequence:

```
(apply concat (take-while seq (map request-fn (iterate (partial + 100) 0))))
```

Is there a way how to concatenate the results sequence lazily, using either `lazy-cat` or something else?

Comment: The [`lazy-cat` *macro*](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/lazy-cat/) evaluates each argument only as required.

Comment: Yes, but how do you apply it to a sequence of arguments?

Comment: Do you really need to concatenate the results, or do you just want to consume them lazily?

Comment: Having the results sequence concatened would make processing them easier. But it's not a strict requirement. I can also map over the results pages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the record, `apply` will consume only enough of the arguments sequence as it needs to determine which arity to call for the provided function. Since the maximum arity of `concat` is 3, `apply` will realize at most 3 items from the underlying sequence.

If those API calls are expensive and you really can't afford to make unnecessary ones, then you will need a function that accepts a seq-of-seqs and lazily concatenates them one at a time. I don't think there's anything built-in, but it's fairly straightforward to write your own:

```
(defn lazy-cat' [colls]
  (lazy-seq
    (if (seq colls)
      (concat (first colls) (lazy-cat' (next colls))))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on apply and a suggestion for lazy-cat'.

Comment: nice answer; btw, when using `next` this function eagerly evaluated 2 items from `colls` even when only requiring 1 evaluation, e.g. `(first (lazy-cat' aseq))`. Using `rest` instead gave the expected behaviour.